# AWS: difference between instance snapshot and volume snapshot

Tags: amazon-web-services, backup, snapshot

What is the difference between an AWS instance snapshot and volume snapshot?

I am implementing "Lifecycle Manager", and my goal is to create a system that will allow for fast recovery of a server in the event of corruption, hacking, or stupid administrators ;)

Previously my approach has been to make an AMI of a base configuration, and then do selective file system/database backups.  Which works, but takes a long time to restore.

Comment: Where have you seen instance snapshots? Never heard of that. There are only snapshots on volumes as far as I am aware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A **volume snapshot** is a snapshot of a single volume.

An **instance snapshot** is a set of snapshots of all attached volumes.

In both cases AWS lifecycle manager only creates EBS snaphots and no AMI. For fast recovery an AMI is very helpful. To schedule AMI creation of your instances you still need a third party tool like AutomatiCloud.

Comment: You don’t need a 3rd party tool. **AWS Backup** can automatically create and expire AMIs on schedule.